# Java, Minecraft Mod Textures don´t load

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

i used to C# and .NET and now i´m trying to get into Java.
But here is my Problem...
I´m trying to make a Mod for Minecraft 1.7.10. I am following a YouTube Tutorial Series but now i´m stuck... My Textures don´t load.

I´m pretty sure the Code is 100% the same as the code from the Video. Also my Paths should be correct. But yea...

```
public static void mainRegistry(){
    initializeBlock();
    registerBlock();
}

public static Block ComStone;


public static void initializeBlock(){
    ComStone = new ComStone(Material.ground).setBlockName("ComStone").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setBlockTextureName(RefStrings.MODID + ":ComStone");

}

public static void registerBlock(){
    GameRegistry.registerBlock(ComStone, ComStone.getUnlocalizedName());
}
```

// Other File

```
public class ComStone extends Block{

protected ComStone(Material p_i45394_1_) {
    super(p_i45394_1_);
}
```

H:\Minecraft Mods\PartArmour\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src\src\main\java\assets\PartArmour\textures\blocks

Hope you can help me.
Thanks
DaNeubi

Comment: Little nitpicking: `ComStone` should be `comStone`. Damn your C# conventions! :p

Comment: nice idea. But doesn´t work...

The missing resources for domain partarmour are:
[18:36:47] [Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]:       textures/items/OStick.png
[18:36:47] [Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]:       textures/blocks/comStone.png

Comment: I know, that wasn't a solution, I just wanted to turn you into a good little Java coder :P

Comment: But on a more serious note: From the stuff you posted it doesn't explicitely say 'file not found', it just says 'TEXTURE ERROR'. Sure that your textures are not corrupted and in the correct format (i.e. 24bpp is guess)?

Comment: didn´t copy all
[Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]:   domain partarmour is missing 2 textures
[Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]:     domain partarmour is missing a resource manager - it is probably a side-effect of automatic texture processing
[00:54:18] [Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]: 
[00:54:18] [Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]:     The missing resources for domain partarmour are:
[00:54:18] [Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]:       textures/items/OStick.png
[00:54:18] [Client thread/ERROR] [TEXTURE ERRORS]:       textures/blocks/ComStone.png

Comment: You might want to look into what a resourcemanager is as it may be required.

Comment: AFAICR I have used forge 1.7.10 and it wasn't a thing so I don't know what is wrong. If actual exceptions are being logged don't be shy digging into the code to see what exactly is throwing them

Comment: found the problem. wrote my modname with capital letters.... dat java